# Kafka: Publish message only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: java, performance, scala, apache-kafka

I am publishing messages to Kafka which are consumed by a number of consumers. These are idempotent so it doesn't matter if one message is consumed multiple times.

However for performance reasons I don't want my (single) producer to publish a message that already exists in the queue. Let's say messages are just ID-strings so it's very easy to check if two messages are equal.

I suppose that Kafka alone isn't made to deal with this kind of performance improvement. Are there any tools or concepts to help dealing with this issue?

Comment: You don't want to publish duplicates because you don't that they were processed multiple times (even idenpotent), or for which reason? You want to not push also messages that were already processed, or only not processed? What infrastructure you can tolerate in addition to Kafka? Did you think about using "compacted" topics?

Comment: Yes - processing them takes quite some time and thus the queue gets filled with duplicates which take time to be processed - this delays the processing of other messages which come after all the duplicates. So my goal is: if I am about to publish a message, I would rather like to check if it is already in the queue (position doesn't matter) and if it is, I don't want to publish it. I guess I need to look into compaction, thank you.

Comment: Do you allow to send new message that was already processed & taken out of queue? Or duplicate should be detected also for already processed messages?

Comment: Yes. Messages that have been processed can be published again and again, they even have to. It's just that if there is already some message `A` in the queue I don't want even more `A`s to be sent to queue because they will all be processed which takes time and doesn't help because they are idempotent.

Comment: Yes, then compacted topics may help - just not forget to send message with the same key & null payload after it's successfully processed

Comment: So that my consumers see that the message is "invalid" and don't do any processing with it? I think I got it. Feels a little bit like a hacky solution but I'ill try it out. Many thanks!

Comment: No, in this case Kafka itself will remove the message with given key from queue...

Comment: Note that with a compacted topic, any consumers that read the older message before the new message is published (compacting the old message) will see the new message (or an even newer message which compacts the new message).

Comment: Why can you not keep track of what you have been sending on the publisher side? Also if you are setting up your producer to reliably only publish once how can this actually be a performance issue if you are trying not to publish duplicates? In what scenarios do your publishers actually publish duplicates (under failure where you fail to track what you sent)? These failure cases seem to be rare so not sure how they would publish a substantial amount of messages. Also look into kafka 0.11 commit and idempotence features.

Answer (score 3):

Kafka is not really well-suited to anything that boils down to looking for a needle in a haystack, because all you can do is linear search.

Getting rarely-more-than-once delivery in Kafka is probably best accomplished by using an external datastore with much better query support (Cassandra or Elasticsearch are two of a great many options here).  Then you have the producer check if the message it wants to write is in that datastore, and you have a consumer of the topic whose sole purpose is to write the messages to that datastore.  Absent size-based retention and a keying scheme where different messages have the same keys, this should be fail-safe (meaning I can't think of how it's not): you won't erroneously decide not to write a message which you should write.